# Cantor-Bendixson Theorem Proof (existence of an ordinal)

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, ordinals, descriptive-set-theory

Let $A$ be a topological space, denote the set of accumulation points of $A$ by $A'$.

If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, we define $A^{(\alpha)}$ by transfinite induction:

$A^{(0)} = A$, $\, \,A^{(\alpha+1)} = (A^{(\alpha)})'\,\,$ and $A^{(\alpha)} = \bigcap_{\beta < \alpha} A^{(\beta)}\,\,$ if $\alpha$ is a nonzero limit ordinal.

Note that $A^{(\beta +1)} \subseteq A^{(\beta)}$ for any ordinal $\beta$.

1) How can we say that there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $A^{(\alpha+1)} = A^{(\alpha)}$?

2) Is it true that if $L=\bigcap_{\alpha} A^{(\alpha)} \neq \emptyset$, then $L=L'$?

Comment: With proper inclusion, surely $|A^{(\alpha)}|\ge|\alpha|$?

Comment: In the last line, what is $\cap_{\alpha}A^{(\alpha)}$ ? Do you mean $\cap_{\alpha\in On}A^{(\alpha)}$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, the class of all ordinals.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no such ordinal, then for every $a\in A$, map it to the least $\alpha$ such that $a\notin A^{(\alpha+1)}$. This is now a surjection onto the class of ordinals. But since $A$ is a set, this is impossible.

For the second question, note that if $x\in L\setminus L'$, then $x\notin L^{(1)}$, so it cannot be in the intersection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I didn't get it clearly. If there is no such ordinal, then $A^{(\alpha +1)} \subsetneq A^{(\alpha)}$ for every ordinal $\alpha$. 1) Does this imply that $\cap_{\alpha} A^{(\alpha)} = \emptyset$? If so, we can map $x \in A$ to the least $\alpha$. 2) But, how can we know that this map is a surjection? For the second answer, it is clear that $x \notin L^{(1)}$ when $x \notin L' = L^{(1)}$. 3) How did you conclude that $x$ cannot be in the intersection in this case?

Comment: 1) No, but why should that matter? It is enough that a subset of $A$ maps onto all the ordinals. 2) We literally assume that $A^{(\alpha)}\neq A^{(\alpha+1)}$, so there *is* some $a$ being mapped to $\alpha$. 3) By the definition of an intersection?

Comment: Okay, so we can consider a surjection from a subset of A onto all the class of ordinals. Could you please explain to me why this is impossible? By the definition of an intersection, can we know that $L \subseteq L^{(1)}$?

Comment: Is it okay to understand like this? If $x \notin L^{(1)}$, then there exists an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that $U \cap L = \{x\}$. If $x$ is in $L$, then for each $\alpha$, we can pick $u \in U$ so that $u \in A^{(\alpha)}$. This gives us a surjection from a subset of $U$ onto the class of ordinals and this is impossible as you pointed out. Thus, $x$ is not in $L$.

Comment: Applying a function to a set results in a set, that is the axiom of replacement.

Comment: Thank you! Is the above argument right? If there is another direct proof for this, could you give me a hint? (I made a mistake there, “If $x$ is in $L$,” -> “Since $x$ is in $L$,”)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Let $A=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Then $A^{(\alpha)}=A$ for all $\alpha \in On$. In particular $A^{(0)}=A^{(1)}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Respectfully disagree with what?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: The point is that for some $\alpha$, $A^{(\alpha)}=A^{(\alpha+1)}$. In the case of $\Bbb R$, that $\alpha$ is already $0$. Yes. The assumption, in my answer, is that this *never happens*, and happening from the start is not quite compatible with my assumption.